# Magento cron job issues newsletters not leaving

Tags: magento-1.8, newsletter

Thank you in advance for any answers here is my magento cron settings in the admin of magento store

Generate Schedules Every 60
 Schedule Ahead for 1
Missed if Not Run Within 60
History Cleanup Every 120
Success History Lifetime 120
 Failure History Lifetime 120

Here is my set up on my server

*/15 * * * * /bin/sh /home/mypath/public_html/cron.sh

Here is what I get when the cron job runs the cron.sh script in a email from my server

Content-type: text/html

If I run cron.php in my browser it returns a empty page

I created a newsletter added it to queue set it for a few minutes later and clicked send newsletter it does not go I checked cron_schedule table in php my admin and it had entries that said pending that were from a month ago I read some where it was safe to delete them so I did (the table structure is still perfect).

Can anyone point me in the right direction it is driving me nuts!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue,I guess its the bug from Magento 1.8~1.9.1.

Try this.
Open the file cron.php in the root directory of Magento and look for (around line 47):

```
$isShellDisabled = (stripos(PHP_OS, ‘win’) === false) ? $isShellDisabled : true;
```

After this line, add:

```
$isShellDisabled = true;
```

Save the file. After a couple minutes the cron should start working.

Thanks for the source:
http://support.xtento.com/wiki/Setting_up_the_Magento_cronjob